# Including external Header files in programs

Tags: 12.04, c

Being using Windows for most of the time and deciding to start programing in ubuntu,I would like to know how I can include the external header file in my programs.Do I download them manually and paste them into the folder wheres the file?Please be kind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a program `print.c` that prints a text:

```
/* print.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "print.h"

int main(void) {
    puts(TEXT);
    return 0;
}
```

and a header file defining that text:

```
/* print.h */
#define TEXT "Hello World!"
```

Then you usually put these files in the same folder. For external dependencies, it depends. Many external dependencies should not be downloaded from a website, but installed from the Ubuntu repositories.

For instance, the OpenGL headers are available from libgl1-mesa-dev (which installs `mesa-common-dev`). 
This makes the headers available in `/usr/include/GL/gl.h`.

In other cases where the header file is not located in the same directory, specify the different include directories while compiling. Example where you have a directory `external-deps` containing header files:

```
cc -I external-deps source.c -o output-program
```

If there are libraries involved (example for an OpenGL program using libGL):

```
cc -I external-deps source.c -o output-program -L path/to/libraries -lGL
```